# Best database admin software for mac?

Tags: database, macos

What's the best database admin software for OSX?

- maintain database schema and data
- run queries
- convert schema from one database type to another
- datapump to move data around
- schema diff tools, ideally able build a script to update a schema
- easy to use

Databases I'm interested in are

- MSSQL
- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- Firebird
- (SQLite)

Prefer one tool for all the databases, rather than one for each database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [SQuirreL SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) in the past.  It's written in Java, so it works on any platform with a decent JVM and any database with a decent JDBC driver.  I think it'll do most, if not all of what you are asking for.

Comment: also found RazorSQL, which is payware.  Pretty similar functionality.

Answer (score 4):

For MySql, use http://www.sequelpro.com/ (foss) or http://www.araelium.com/querious/ (paid)

Answer (score 3):

For just postgres, pgAdmin3 has gotten better in the last few releases and works fine in OS X. I've also used SQuirrel, which works on jdbc compliant db's, but it's been a while.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Aqua Data studio](http://www.aquafold.com/index.html) 6 at work on a daily basis, with SQL Server, Sybase IQ and Netezza.  It's convenient not having to switch tools all the time. It also has a handy SQL prettier that helps keep my blood pressure low when people send me mangled SQL to look at.  Netezza is unsupported but works fine with generic ODBC/JDBC.

While it is a java app the only time I really run into problems is when I run a query that returns to many rows (over 100k).  You can set the limits and or play with memory but every once in a while I shoot myself in the foot and bang on my keyboard.

I run windows but linux and mac are also supported.

Nice just noticed that version 7 has built in pivot tables.  That will save me from cutting and pasting datasets to excel!

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL, you could try:

1. [MySQL Admin](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)
2. [PHP Mysql Admin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) (if you don't mind installing a PHP web app)
3. [Oracle's SQLDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) (works with MySQL also with a little bit of config)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a mac developer that wanted some tools for some of these as well, so I built a few tools.

- [SQLPro for SQLite](https://www.sqlitepro.com/)
- [SQLPro for MSSQL](http://macsqlclient.com/) and
- [SQLPro for MySQL](http://mysqlui.com/)

SQLPro for SQLite is the oldest and has gone over fairly well with a 4 star average rating and great reviews.

SQLPro for MSSQL it a newer app built for connecting to MSSQL databases (specifically I wanted Azure support, but it does other versions as well), which has also been getting great reviews.

I have also been asked by a few people for a Postgres version, so that will be coming in the near future.